# Last_Value returning multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

I have a table (SROEnquiry) as listed in the snapshot below:
Data.jpg

I’m using `Last_Value()` to get the last entry of each StudentNumberstudent on the table. StudentNumber 'Y1293926' is used as example.

The script is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(StudentNumber),
       LAST_VALUE(Arrears) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY StudentNumber ORDER BY RecordID) AS LastValue  
FROM SROEnquiry 
WHERE StudentNumber = 'Y1293926'
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

The expected result is:

```
StudentNumber   LastValue
Y1293926        0.00
```

What is wrong with the script that it brings back 4 values instead of only one?

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the correct frame with `LAST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    StudentNumber,
    LAST_VALUE(Arrears) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentNumber ORDER BY RecordID
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastValue  
FROM SROEnquiry 
WHERE StudentNumber = 'Y1293926'
```

Comment: Nice one Tim, this shoudl be marked as an answer. Some explenation about the extra syntax is here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Answer (score 1):

`LAST VALUE` returns the last value of the window created by the `OVER` clause. The window expands while records are being ordered by `RecordID`, hence `LAST VALUE` fetches a different value each time.

Also, `DISTINCT` is applied to *both* fields of the `SELECT` clause. Hence you get one record for each value returned by `LAST VALUE`.

Why not just use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 StudentNumber, Arrears AS LastValue  
FROM SROEnquiry 
WHERE StudentNumber = 'Y1293926'
ORDER BY RecordID DESC
```

Comment: This would return *`NULL`* right? even though his wanted answer would be 0.00

Comment: Title `SQL Server 2016` ... nice cap by the way, how did you get it?

Comment: `RecordID` is not included in the sample data provided in the OP. Hence I am just guessing that `ORDER BY RecordID DESC` results in the last record being returned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it is really a nice one! I gave a nice answer yesterday, perhaps it is because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(StudentNumber),
       LAST_VALUE(Arrears) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY StudentNumber ORDER BY StudentNumber) AS LastValue  
FROM SROEnquiry 
WHERE StudentNumber = 'Y1293926'
```

Comment: Your code may work but please include some description to explain why

Comment: It is exactly the same query as in the question.

Comment: OP's  problem is getting four records instead of one because of "order by RecordId" column so i just changes..